# Implement Unmonopoly game using priority queues?

Tags: java, algorithm

A group of children wants to play a game, called UnMonopoly , wherein each turn the player with the most money must give half of his/her money to the player with the least amount of money. After the turns are completed announce the person with the highest money as WINNER. Implement this game by taking the number of turns and players. (Hint: Use Priority queues)

Sample Input:

Number of players: n

Number of turns: m

Enter each player details and money

Output:

Winner is: Player Name

This is my question, I have written a code. Is this a correct way to implement or are there any flaws in it. Is there a better implementation with smaller time complexity?

Here is my code,

```
import java.util.*;

class Player implements Comparator<Player> {

    String name;
    int money;
    Player(String name, int m) {
        this.name = name;
        money = m;
    }
    public Player() {
        this.money = 0;
        this.name = null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "NAME: "+name+"\nMONEY: "+money;
    }

    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        return p2.money - p1.money;
    }
}

public class Unmonopoly {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player pl = new Player();
        Stack<Player> pla = new Stack<Player>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of players: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        PriorityQueue<Player> play = new PriorityQueue<Player>(n,pl);
        System.out.println("Enter player details: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Player p = new Player(sc.next(),sc.nextInt());
            play.add(p);
        }

        for(Player p: play) {
            System.out.println("Name: "+p.name+"\nMoney: "+p.money);
        }

        System.out.println("\nEnter the number of turns: ");
        int turns = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < turns; i++) {
            Player max = play.peek();
            max.money = max.money / 2;
            while(!play.isEmpty()) {
                pla.push(play.peek());
                play.remove();
            }
            Player min = pla.pop();
            pla.push(min);
            System.out.println("Player with min money is: \n"+min);
            min.money = min.money + max.money;
            while(!pla.isEmpty()) {
                play.add(pla.peek());
                pla.pop();
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("**************WINNER************** \n\n\tNAME:   "+play.peek().name+"\n\tMONEY:  "+play.peek().money);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your complexity is O(N * M * log(N)), because you recreate the priority queue each turn.

Not sure how valid the hint is, as you need both the minimum and the maximum player each turn, so a better data structure might be a TreeSet - it allows you to get straight to both the minimum and maximum. The complexity would then be O(M * log(N))..

The main loop in such a case would simply be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < turns; i++) {
    Player min = players.pollFirst();
    Player max = players.pollLast();

    min.money += max.money / 2;
    max.money -= max.money / 2;

    players.add(min);
    players.add(max);
}
```

Both `poll` operations as well as `add` are O(log(N))..

Comment: Actually I am a beginner I am not aware of tree set yet and also I was restricted to use priority queues.

Comment: Are you sure you're restricted? It looks like it's a hint, not a requirement.. In any case, I have no idea how to do this with priority queues with improved time complexity, and it's very easy with a TreeSet..

Comment: Yes. My instructor has given me a restriction to use only priority queues. Anyway thanks your suggestion I will surely implement when I get to know about Tree Set.

Comment: Well, either your instructor is confused, or I am :) If there indeed exists a faster algorithm with priority queues, please write an answer here, I'd be very interested.